# Aliasing class symbol name

Tags: c++

I have a class inside a few nested namespaces, `android::hardware::camera::common::V1_0::helper::CameraParameters`, that I want to make available as `android::CameraParameters`, so, in the compiled binary, the symbols pointing to that class would look like `_ZN7android16CameraParameters` rather than `_ZN7android8hardware6camera6common4V1_06helper16CameraParameters`. Is this possible?

I need to do this to provide some missing symbols to another (prebuilt, with no usable source code available, library) without editing the source files.

Comment: @JeJo That's the first thing I tried, and the resulting symbols were still the complete namespace ones.

Comment: In addition to JeJo: What if you derive `android::CameraParameters` from `android::hardware::camera::common::V1_0::helper::CameraParameters`? It would make something like a "thin wrapper". [Sample on wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/skNOsT39uK0av4aD)

Answer (score 0):

You can define a namespace alias:

```
namespace foo {
    namespace bar {
         namespace something {
             //code
         }
    }
}

namespace alias = foo::bar::something;
```

Now you can use `alias` instead of `foo::bar::something`

So in your case just add this:

```
namespace android {
    namespace CameraParameters = hardware::camera::common::V1_0::helper::CameraParameters;
}
```

or ( not sure if this is legit)

```
namespace android::CameraParameters = android::hardware::camera::common::V1_0::helper::CameraParameters;
```

Edit: To make sure the symbols are pointing to that class, you can use the **gcc** alias:

```
void alias() __attribute__((alias ("toBeAliased")))
```

or you can do it by passing the right symbol to the linker:

```
--defsym=oldname=newname
```

Comment: I don't think that will change the externally visible symbol.

Comment: I can't get aliases to work, but the namespace solution doesn't work.

Comment: @CozzmyCosmin You tried the `--defsym` ? Or are there too many symbols to manually change

Comment: I had 150 symbols. Anyway, I gave up that idea and just decided to hack it up another way.